# PieChart is not refreshed in Avalonia 11 with CommunityToolkit MVVM 8. It worked fine with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, livecharts, avalonia

I have  MVVM Avalonia 11 project that uses Community Toolkit MVVM 8.2
It runs on Windows 11.
I use PieChart of Livecharts 2 that has two visual states.  With Avalonia timer of 1 second I change between  the states and expect to get a "like animation" behavior of the PieChart. That originally worked with Reactive UI. With Community Toolkit it's just frozen and refreshed only if mouse hovers over.
XAML file :

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Testt.ViewModels"
          xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Testt.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Testt">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <lvc:PieChart
         Series="{Binding Series}"   
         InitialRotation="45"
         MaxAngle="270"
         Total="100">
    </lvc:PieChart>

</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.Measure;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using Avalonia.Threading;

namespace Testt.ViewModels;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int index;
    private DispatcherTimer RefreshTimer;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        index = 0;
        Series = ChangeGB1();
        UpdateSeriesTimer();  
    }
    [ObservableProperty]
    private IEnumerable<ISeries> _series;
    public void UpdateSeriesTimer()
    {
        RefreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, UpdateSeries);
        RefreshTimer.Start();
    }
 
    public void UpdateSeries(object?    sender,EventArgs  args)  
    {
         Series = (index++ % 2 == 0) ? ChangeGB1() : ChangeGB2();
    }
    public IEnumerable<ISeries> ChangeGB1()
    {
        var gb = new GaugeBuilder()
            .WithLabelsSize(20)
            .WithLabelsPosition(PolarLabelsPosition.Start)
            .WithLabelFormatter(point => $"{point.Coordinate.PrimaryValue} {point.Context.Series.Name}")
            .WithInnerRadius(20)
            .WithOffsetRadius(8)
            .WithBackgroundInnerRadius(20)

            .AddValue(30, "Vanessa")
            .AddValue(50, "Charles")
            .AddValue(70, "Ana")

            .BuildSeries();
        return gb;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ISeries> ChangeGB2()
    {
        var gb = new GaugeBuilder()
            .WithLabelsSize(20)
            .WithLabelsPosition(PolarLabelsPosition.Start)
            .WithLabelFormatter(point => $"{point.Coordinate.PrimaryValue} {point.Context.Series.Name}")
            .WithInnerRadius(20)
            .WithOffsetRadius(8)
            .WithBackgroundInnerRadius(20)

            .AddValue(20, "Vanessa")
            .AddValue(30, "Charles")
            .AddValue(40, "Ana")

            .BuildSeries();
        return gb;
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

I suspect a bug in the Avalonia code rather than in LiveCharts since I detected the same behavior in DataGrid control. I'm looking for a work around.

Comment: Your issue with DataGrid is that it's not refreshed or simply not displayed? For the latter you may be missing a style definition in App.axaml.